# How to insert code into a code block?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to insert a piece of code in my question and I am receiving this message:

> Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

These are the steps I'm taking to copy/paste the code from the IDE in VS2008:

1. Copy and Paste the code
2. Select the code
3. Click the `{}` button

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message gives you the exact solution: Add some context or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code. Do you have text in your question other than what's formatted as code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, you shouldn't be posting code alone with nothing else.  You need to *explain* what your question is, identify what is wrong, tell us what you're expecting and what you actually got.  It helps nobody if we don't understand your problem.

To be able to ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), just posting your code in the body will not be enough.  You need to include details.  If you somehow get around this, don't consider it ok, it is something that should have been stopped in the first place.  Seeing that you were not able to get your question through, it seems like it's working just fine.

Comment: I have already succeeded in posting my question. Thanks for your reply.